# Efficient algorithm for grouping elements and counting duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

I've got an array of objects. If one property of the object is the same like in another object, I consider it to be a duplicate, I want to group objects by this property and store information about how many times the "duplicate" occured.

For example:

> X A B O
>
> Y X Z I
>
> Y X Z U
>
> X A B L
>
> Y X Z K

I want to group by the first value. Another two properties are the same in each duplicate too, but comparing the first value will be enough. I need to display to the user a result that looks like:

> Y X Z (3)
>
> X A B (2)

I know there are some algorithms for it but I'm looking for an efficient one. Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you expose the algorithms you're talking about first, and tell us why it's not efficient enough for you needs. Have you actually tried them?

Comment: Provided that *property* can be transformed to a valid identifier, you'll need only one pass through the array. Won't get much better anyway.

Comment: Do you consider using Lodash? There is a [`groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#groupBy) function.

Answer (score 0):

The following may be an option. Create an object which will represent the occurrence of each property looking something like so:

```
{
  a: 1,
  b: 1,
  c: 2
  d: 4
}
```

Giving this object you can go ahead and group the occurrence ending up with an object looking like so:

```
{
  1: [ 'a', 'b' ],
  2: [ 'c' ],
  4: [ 'd' ]
}
```

Here is an example, hope it helps.

```js
var data = [
  {x: 'x', a: 'a', b: 'b'},
  {y: 'y', x: 'x', z: 'z'},
  {y: 'y', x: 'x', z: 'z'},
  {x: 'x', c: 'c', b: 'b'}
];

function countOccurrence ( arr ) {
  var dubs = {};
  arr.forEach ( function ( item ) {
    Object.keys( item ).forEach ( function ( prop ) {
      ( dubs[prop] ) ? dubs[prop] += 1 : dubs[prop] = 1;
    });
  });
  return dubs;
}

function groupByOccurrence ( obj ) {
  return Object.keys ( obj ).reduce ( function ( a, b ) {
    ( a[obj[b]] ) ? a[obj[b]].push ( b ) : a[obj[b]] = [b];
    return a;
  }, {});
}

console.log ( groupByOccurrence ( countOccurrence ( data ) ) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of a tree and counting the nodes.

```js
function iter(object, path) {
    var keys = Object.keys(object)

    if (keys.length === 1) {
        result.push(path.join('') + ' (' + object._ + ')');
        return;
    }
    keys.some(function (k) {
        if (k === '_') {
            return;
        }
        if (!path.length) {
            iter(object[k], path.concat(k));
            return;
        }
        if (object._ !== object[k]._) {
            result.push(path.join('') + ' (' + object._ + ')');
            return true;
        }
        iter(object[k], path.concat(k) );
    });
}

var data = [{ X: 1, A: 1, B: 1, O: 1 }, { Y: 1, X: 1, Z: 1, I: 1 }, { Y: 1, X: 1, Z: 1, U: 1 }, { X: 1, A: 1, B: 1, L: 1 }, { Y: 1, X: 1, Z: 1, K: 1 }, { i: 0, k: 0 }, { i: 0, k: 0 }],
    grouped = {},
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (o) {
    Object.keys(o).reduce(function (r, k) {
        r[k] = r[k] || {};
        r[k]._ = (r[k]._ || 0) + 1;
        return r[k];
    }, grouped);
});

iter(grouped, []);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```